# how to draw an pixel animation on a canvas?

Tags: android

I need your help.

I'm working on android Toy project that manipulating led.
But sometimes I leave the led module at home. so, i want to make a function that check the LED from a distance.
I got a two-dimensional array and using this, play animation on led.
What I'm thinking about now is using this two-dimensional array to operate in imageview, but I can't think of a way.
led module shape is width:6 height:10.

```
image_array_list[][]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

//two frame led

element is only 0 and 1(off or on) and led has a 6*10 pixel.
i want to show this in imageview...
but when i covert this array to bitmap(1=>black, 0=>white), it's so distorted.
i searched all day, but i cant find a solution.

plz help me!

Comment: use canvas,drawRect with 1 size by x,y

Comment: Thanks. i tried!
but I don't use this function now.